Fast forward and rewind video on YouTube in background mode
Is it possible to fast forward and rewind videos on YouTube in the mobile app in the background, for example using a Bluetooth remote control?

This might be what you're looking for: https://netclicker.tv
Don't think they have controls in background mode yet but you can just turn off your phone when not using to control, it reconnects when opened again, and it uses WiFi.

I have a feeling the question is actually talking about YouTube Premium's background play, but after re-reading it again, the interpretation could be ambiguous.

@AndrewT. yeah it is ambiguous, it was the bluetooth bit that made me think its not the YouTube's app in background mode because you definitely don't need bluetooth to tap those controls
